# Integral over a circular sector

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Actually having a bit of trouble calculating the integral:

$$\iint_D\sqrt{1 - y^2}dA$$

where $D$ is $r \in [0, 1], \theta \in [\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}].$

I know that

$$\int_{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}r\sqrt{1 - r^2 \cdot sin^2{\theta}} \cdot drd\theta  $$

but a simple substitution isn't getting me anywhere. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a substitution. If we let $u=r\sin(\theta)$, then the integral is

$$I=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sin(\theta)}\frac{u\sqrt{1-u^2}}{\sin^2(\theta)}dud\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I think I can. I really gotta step up my substition game. I honestly am pretty lost at _what_ to substitute sometimes. Thanks a lot.